# In connect to server, there is no server type option in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, webdav, network-drive

I want to mount my box.com webdav into my Ubuntu 14.04, but when I clicked the “connect to server” option in my home folder, I guess there is supposed to be an option for the type of server I want to connect to, as there was on previous versions. Where is that option now?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try this out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202761

Comment: thats with all those terminal command stuff those consumes much time rather i would apperiate simple way

Comment: This seems to be the only way, unless one of use were nice enough to write you a bash script, but I wouldn't get my hopes up on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 'Connect to Server' dialog window, use 'davs://dav.box.com/dav' in the server address field and click on connect button, then, it would ask you to enter your box.com's username and password. Hope this helps..